# Error 1006: Not a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am getting the error in the title when trying to access a method in another class. I have the main class, ZombieBots, which is linked to a movie clip of the same name. I then have 3 more movie clips which all get added to the ZombieBots clip during runtime, and each of these have their own classes.

When I attempt to access a method within the ZombieBots class from one of the other 3 classes, I get error 1006.

The function I am attempting to access in the ZombieBots class, that cannot be accessed:

```
    package  {
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class ZombieBots extends MovieClip{

        private var pLives:int;
        private var pScore:int;
        private var pSkill:int;
        private var pItems:int;
        private var characterMC:Character;
        private var cGameObjs:Array;

        public function ZombieBots() {
            /*cGameObjs = new Array();
            addCharacter();
            addItems();
            addBots();

            pLives = 5 - pSkill;
            pScore = 0;

            pItems = pSkill + 5;*/
            resetGame();
        }

        private function  addCharacter():void{
            trace("Adding the character");

            if (!characterMC){
            var myBorder:Rectangle = new Rectangle(35,35,600,480);
            var myXY:Array = [38, 400];
            var myChar:int = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
            var myKeys:Array = [37,39,38,40];
            var myDistance:int = myChar * 3;
            characterMC = new Character(myBorder, myXY, myKeys, myChar, myDistance);
            addChild(characterMC);
            }
            else{

                characterMC.x = 38;
                characterMC.y = 510;


                characterMC.gotoAndStop(pSkill);

            }
        }


    private function  addItems():void{
        trace("yeah boi");
        var mySkill:int = Math.ceil(Math.random() *3);
        var myMaxItems:int = mySkill + 5;
        trace(mySkill);
        trace(myMaxItems);
        trace(this);
        for (var i:int = 0; i < myMaxItems; i++){
            var thisItem:Item = new Item(this, characterMC, mySkill);
            thisItem.name = "item" + i;
            cGameObjs.push(thisItem);
            addChild(thisItem);
        }

        pSkill = mySkill;
        updateScores();
    }

        private function  addBots():void{
            trace("adding the bots bra");
            var myBorder:Rectangle =  new Rectangle(100,100,400,350);
            var mySkill:int = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
            var myMaxBots:int = mySkill +10;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < myMaxBots; i++){
                var thisBot:Bot = new Bot(myBorder, characterMC, mySkill);
                thisBot.name = "bot" + i;
                cGameObjs.push(thisBot);
                addChild(thisBot);

            }
        }

        private function  updateScores():void{
            scoreDisplay.text = String(pScore);
            itemsDisplay.text = String(pItems);
            livesDisplay.text = String(pLives);
            msgDisplay.text = "Orc Invasion";

        }

        public function  updateLives(myBot:MovieClip):void{
            trace("update lives");
            pLives--;
            pScore -= myBot.getPts();
            var myIndex:int = cGameObjs.indexOf(myBot);
            cGameObjs.splice(myIndex, 1);
            if (pLives > 0){
                updateScores();

            }

            else{
                gameOver(false);
            }
        }

        public function updateItems(myItem:MovieClip):void{
        trace("update items");
        pItems--;
        pScore += myItem.getPts();
        var myIndex:int = cGameObjs.indexOf(myItem);
        cGameObjs.splice(myIndex, 1);
        if (pItems > 0){
            updateScores();
        }

        else{
            gameOver(true);
        }

    }

        private function  gameOver(bool:Boolean):void{
            trace("Game over dawg");
            updateScores();
            if(bool){
                msgDisplay.text = "Good job buddy";
            }
            else{
                msgDisplay.text = "You suck dawg";
            }
            removeLeftovers();
        }

        private function  resetGame():void{
            playAgainBtn.visible = false;
            playAgainBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playAgain);
            cGameObjs = new Array();
            addCharacter();
            addItems();
            addBots();

            pLives = 5 - pSkill;
            pScore = 0;

            pItems = pSkill + 5;
            updateScores();
        }

        private function  playAgain(evt:MouseEvent):void{
            resetGame();
        }

        private function removeLeftovers():void{
            trace("Removing leftover items and bots");
            for each(var myObj in cGameObjs){
                myObj.hasHitMe();
                myObj = null;
            }
            playAgainBtn.visible = true;
            playAgainBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playAgain);
        }





    }

}
```

and this is the class where I am attempting to access this function within one of the other 3 classes:

```
    package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import ZombieBots;

    public class Item extends MovieClip{
        private var cNumItem:int;
        private var cNumPts:int;
        private var characterMC:MovieClip;
        private var ZombieBot:ZombieBots;

        public function Item(myZB:ZombieBots, myChar:MovieClip, mySkill:int=1) {
            ZombieBot = myZB;
            cNumItem = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (mySkill * 3 + 1));
            characterMC = myChar;
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initItem);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkCollision);
        }


        private function initItem(evt:Event):void{

            this.gotoAndStop(cNumItem);
            cNumPts = cNumItem * 25;
            setPosition();
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initItem);
        }

        private function setPosition():void{

            this.x = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)*50);
            this.y = (Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)*35);

        }

        private function checkCollision(evt:Event){
            if (characterMC.hitTestObject(this)){

                ZombieBot.updateItems(this);
                hasHitMe();
            }
        }

        public function hasHitMe():void{
            trace("remove");
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkCollision);
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
        }

        public function getPts():int{
            return cNumPts;
        }
    }

}
```

can anyone help?

Comment: myItem.getPts(); you have no method like getPts() in Item class

Comment: @Bolzano, The entire class is 200 Lines. I am supplying an example of the problem.

Comment: yea but you have to add definition of your functions or methods or classes which used in main code ... otherwise how could we find your bug. its obvious you are calling something but its not defined as function.

Comment: @Bolzano Fair enough, but the problem is that when trying to access the updateItems class, it can't be found.

Comment: ok additionaly to "prototypical's answer" send your ZombieBots instance as owner (or displayContainer its up to you) to Item to reach that instance from Item class. like "var item:Item = new Item(this);//in ZombieBots Class"... or make your main class as singleton to reach instance easily. these are solutions but not the bests. it can be different depends on your pattern .

Comment: @rakeshisu I am not looking to play programming charades here. What I have posted will work, but as I said I am making some assumptions. Am I supposed to just question you about these assumptions one by one until we hit the right one ? Have you debugged to see what root is ? is it null ? I have no idea how you have things set up, because I can't see the code. You might not think some of it is relevant, but then again, you are the one with the broken code here. right ?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the null error is on the line you specified ? And not in the updateItems method ? Post the exact error message with line number.

Comment: @prototypical I apologize. I am just struggling to find out what code you need to see. I understand that I am the one having the problem and I am extremely grateful for your help. I traced root, which is returning "[object MainTimeline]." It is definitely not null. 

Again, I apologize. I am really terrible at flash.

Comment: The error message: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Item/checkCollision()[C:\Users\Jesse\Desktop\MainMenu\Item.as:39]

Comment: We are playing programming charades. Can you please post the code so we can see where ZombieBots is instantiated ? If it's not root, the implementation you chose is not going to work as Item will not have a reference to that class via root.  -- for the record, I don't think that's the best way to achieve what you want, but I'm working within your current implementation.

Comment: I posted all my code. Hopefully this will help with understanding. Sorry.

Comment: @prototypical looks like root type is not ZombieBots because of null object reference.like you said its not best way to achieve but as i said before just send ZombieBots instance to Item class when creating them. you can assign it in Item's constructor to private var in Item class then you can reach whenever you want ...

Comment: Have news for you. Your private var is not what is making it work. It's the import that was created that made it work. You aren't even using the ZombieBot property in your code, and it never gets assigned.

Comment: Based on the code you just posted, ZombieBots seems to be your document class, unless you are instantiating it in another class. What is the class that you are using as your document class, if not ZombieBots ? Yes, the problem is solved, but I have to believe you are completely misunderstanding why. If you are good with that, it's all good.

Comment: "Document class" is a new term to me, I am afraid. Is the document class the class which I have linked to the fla? Or is it something else? I do not have a .as linked to my .fla right now.

Comment: I posted the code that is working. After I created the private var I added it to my constructor as well as creating it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateItems` is not a MovieClip method. It's a method of your ZombieBots class.

Casting your ZombieBots instance (which I am assuming is root) as a MovieClip, will only allow you to use it's class methods or methods it has inherited.

Try this :

```
var zombieBotsInstance:ZombieBots = root as ZombieBots;
zombieBotsInstance.updateItems(this);
```

Comment: Woops, that's my mistake. edited original post with the correct code.

Comment: I tried this, but I am now getting null object reference on the zombieBotsInstance.updateItems(this) line.

I have a feeling that trying to access the root in this way is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Post your updated code. I am making a few assumptions here. What is root ? Is it a ZombieBots instance - ie document class ?

Comment: The ZombieBots class is linked to a movie clip of the same name and within this MovieClip I add Items(another MovieClip linked to the Items class). The document class(if I am understanding the term correctly) is the class linked to the .fla file, which is not accessed or referred to in ZombieBots.

Comment: So... root is NOT your ZombieBots instance. Therefore, why would it be able to all a method in that instance ?? I gave you an answer based on the assumption that root was a ZombieBots instance.

Comment: Very good example of how code very relevant to this issue, was not seen as relevant to provide in the question.